# Вывести в консоль сумму введенных пользователем чисел с помощью Цикла for. C#

Tags: c#, циклы, счетчики

Нужно заполнить коллекцию из 10 целых чисел с клавиатуры (заполнить данными от пользователя) и посчитать сумму всех введенных пользователем чисел.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < 10;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
            Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine($" {i+i}");
        }
    }
}
```

Сделал вот такой код, но это не сумма всех введенных чисел, а сложение переменной на саму себе с шагом +1. Помогите, пожалуйста исправить мой код

Comment: Вам нужно создать переменную в которой будет накапливаться сумма и внутри цикла добавлять к ней текущий элемент.

Comment: Неужели не интересно решить такое простое учебное задание самостоятельно? `List<T>` изучали? Был тут один спрашивающий, писал, что ему это программирование вообще не сдалось, а у вас как с предметом, тоже нелюбовь?

Comment: @aepot Я +- 3 дня назад начал изучение. Конкретно с этой задачей не могу справиться... А про List вообще забыл, спасибо что напомнили.

Comment: а где в решении хотя бы одна коллекция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберу всю задачу с самого начала.

#### Присваивание

Вот смотрите, присваивание в шарпе работает просто

```cs
// переменная = значение;
i = 3;
```

Чтобы оно сработало, переменная должна быть ранее объявлена. Но переменную можно объявить так же вместе с присваиванием, для этого перед ее именем надо написать ее тип. Нельзя дважды объявить одну и ту же переменную в текущем блоке кода.

```cs
// тип переменная = значение;
int i = 3;
```

#### Вывод в консоль

Как что-то написать в консоль, вы уже знаете. Но строки для вывода в консоль можно дополнять переменными, для этого есть несколько способов.

```cs
// конкатенация строк
Console.WriteLine("Значение i = " + i);
// использование встроенного форматирования метода WriteLine
Console.WriteLine("Значение i = {0}", i);
// интерполяция строк
Console.WriteLine($"Значение i = {i}");
```

Вывод в консоль будет у всех трех способов одинаковый. Что именно использовать - вам решать. Я предпочитаю [интерполяцию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Конечно со строками много всякого можно делать, но для вашей задачи этих знаний хватит.

#### Коллекции

Для начала, вам стоит познакомиться двумя из них: массивом и списком.

Как оно объявляется:

```cs
// массив
// тип[] переменая = new тип[количество_элементов];
int[] array = new int[10];
// список
// List<тип> переменая = new List<тип>();
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

Первое, что бросается здесь в глаза - это то что у массива при создании его экземпляра (`new` создает экземпляр объекта) количество элементов массива известно заранее, а у списка их можно добавлять по ходу дела.

Здесь важно условие вашей задачи "коллекцию из 10 целых чисел". Количество известно заранее? Да, значит используем массив.

*ВАЖНО: нумерация элементов, то есть их порядковые номера в массиве начинаются с нуля `0`.*

#### Циклы

Можно было бы написать 10 строк кода и ввести 10 значений, но что если их 2000 или еще больше... Хотя что это я - вы уже знакомы с циклом `for`. Берем всё, что я написал выше, собираем вместе, получаем следующий блок кода.

```cs
int[] a = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine("Введите 10 чисел.");
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Введите a[{i}]: ");
    a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // то же самое, что Convert.ToInt32(), но мне так больше нравится 
}
```

Вот и готова первая часть задачи. Имеем массив из 10 элементов, заполненный пользователем.

Кстати, обратите внимание, у вас в коде `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` вы никуда не присваиваете число, считанное с клавиатуры.

#### Математика

Чтобы посчитать сумму элементов, нужно ее где-то хранить. Окей, объявим еще одну переменную.

```cs
int sum = 0;
```

Чтобы что-то прибавить к переменной, то есть не просто присвоить, а учитывая текущее ее значение - прибавить к ней, можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```cs
sum = sum + 3;
```

Или есть более короткая запись того же самого:

```cs
sum += 3;
```

Теперь точно так же, как считывалось оно с клавиатуры, только заменим тело цикла на суммирование.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    sum += a[i];
}
```

Ну и выведем консоль

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма 10 элементов массива: {sum}");
```

Готово. Думаю, вам не составит труда теперь собрать это воедино и заставить работать.